# ORA-00904: "DAY": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE classroom (
    building VARCHAR (10),
    room_number VARCHAR (10),
    capacity INT,
primary key( building, room_number));

CREATE TABLE department (
    dept_name VARCHAR(20),
    building VARCHAR(10), 
    budget DOUBLE PRECISION,
    PRIMARY KEY (dept_name)
   
);

CREATE TABLE instructor (
    ID VARCHAR(5),
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    dept_name VARCHAR(20),
    salary DOUBLE PRECISION,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) REFERENCES department (dept_name)
);

CREATE TABLE student (
    ID VARCHAR(5),
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    dept_name VARCHAR(20),
    tot_cred NUMERIC(2, 0),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) REFERENCES department (dept_name)
);

CREATE TABLE course (
    course_id VARCHAR(10),
    title VARCHAR(30),
    dept_name VARCHAR(20),
    credits NUMERIC(2, 0),
    PRIMARY KEY (course_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) REFERENCES department (dept_name)
);

CREATE TABLE time_slot (
    time_slot_id VARCHAR(10),
    day NUMERIC(2, 0),
    start_time DATE,
    end_time DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (time_slot_id, day, start_time)
);

CREATE TABLE section (
    course_id VARCHAR(10),
    sec_id VARCHAR(10),
    semester VARCHAR(10),
    year NUMERIC(4, 0),
    building VARCHAR(10),
    room_number VARCHAR(10),
    time_slot_id VARCHAR(10),
    PRIMARY KEY (course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
    FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES course (course_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (time_slot_id, day, start_time) REFERENCES time_slot (time_slot_id, day, start_time),
    FOREIGN KEY (building, room_number) REFERENCES classroom (building, room_number)
);
```

> ORA-00904: "DAY": invalid identifier is the error I'm receiving

I also have to add a foreign key in the department table
foreign key(building) referencing classroom(building)

but I wasn't able to do it cause classroom has compound primary keys

I added in a unique constraint to fix that

alter table classroom
add constraint unique_building unique(building)

but then it threw an error when I tried to create the section table

so I removed the foreign key in the department table, and thought I'll add the unique constraint after running the section table but the I got this error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your problem has nothing to do with Raul's answer; `day` isn't reserved:

```
SQL> create table test (day number);

Table created.
```

---

It is about the fact that - while creating table named `section` - you tried to create foreign key to `time_slot` table. As

- foreign key's columns have to match primary/unique key's columns
- `time_slot` table's primary key is set to `time_slot_id, day, start_time`
- however, `section` table **does not contain** `day` nor `start_time` columns
- Oracle reported the first column's mismatch, and that way `day` - therefore, you got

  > ORA-00904: "DAY": invalid identifier

---

As of other problems you reported:

- foreign key from `department` to `classroom`: as already said, columns must match; you can't reference only `building` to both `building, room_number` so you'd either have to add `room_number` to `department` table, or set a different primary key column for `classroom` >> that's what I'd suggest you to do.  (No problem in keeping unique key on building and room number, though)

  - why wouldn't you use *neutral* ID values for primary keys? Choose either identity columns (if your database supports them - as in my example), or combination of sequence and database trigger.
  - then modify `department` as well so that datatypes match

Therefore:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE classroom (
  2      id_building number generated always as identity primary key,
  3      building VARCHAR (10),
  4      room_number VARCHAR (10),
  5      capacity INT,
  6  unique ( building, room_number));

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE department (
  2      dept_name VARCHAR(20),
  3      id_building number constraint fk_dept_class references classroom (id_building),
  4      budget DOUBLE PRECISION,
  5      PRIMARY KEY (dept_name)
  6  );

Table created.
```

However, I don't like having department **name** as a primary key; names are usually bad choice for such a purpose. I'd create a new `id_department` identity column for a primary key.

A few other tables are OK:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE instructor (
  2      ID VARCHAR(5),
  3      name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  4      dept_name VARCHAR(20),
  5      salary DOUBLE PRECISION,
  6      PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  7      FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) REFERENCES department (dept_name)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE student (
  2      ID VARCHAR(5),
  3      name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  4      dept_name VARCHAR(20),
  5      tot_cred NUMERIC(2, 0),
  6      PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  7      FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) REFERENCES department (dept_name)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE course (
  2      course_id VARCHAR(10),
  3      title VARCHAR(30),
  4      dept_name VARCHAR(20),
  5      credits NUMERIC(2, 0),
  6      PRIMARY KEY (course_id),
  7      FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) REFERENCES department (dept_name)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE time_slot (
  2      time_slot_id VARCHAR(10),
  3      day NUMERIC(2, 0),
  4      start_time DATE,
  5      end_time DATE,
  6      PRIMARY KEY (time_slot_id, day, start_time)
  7  );

Table created.
```

Finally, `section`: as I already said, this table doesn't contain `day` nor `start_time` columns so you **can't** reference `time_slot`'s primary key. I simply commented it out:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE section (
  2      course_id VARCHAR(10),
  3      sec_id VARCHAR(10),
  4      semester VARCHAR(10),
  5      year NUMERIC(4, 0),
  6      building VARCHAR(10),
  7      room_number VARCHAR(10),
  8      time_slot_id VARCHAR(10),
  9      PRIMARY KEY (course_id, sec_id, semester, year),
 10      FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES course (course_id),
 11      --FOREIGN KEY (time_slot_id, day, start_time) REFERENCES time_slot (time_slot_id, day, start_time),
 12      FOREIGN KEY (building, room_number) REFERENCES classroom (building, room_number)
 13  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

But, **of course** that commenting part of code that doesn't work isn't correct solution.

I'd suggest you to think it over and recreate all tables. Use **identity** columns for primary keys and you won't have problems with foreign keys. That's what you did in e.g. `instructor`, `student` and `course` tables.

There can be situations that require composite unique keys - so set them, no problem. But leave primary key *alone*.

Apart from that, Oracle suggests we use `varchar2` datatype instead of `varchar`

Comment: the above code was part of an exercise where I had no flexibilty in creating my primary keys or what attributes go in each table

Comment: University Database Schema:
Student (ID, name,dept-name, tot-cred)
Instructor(ID, name, dept-name, salary)
Course (Course-id, title,dept-name, credits)
Takes (ID, course-id, sec-id, semester, year, grade)
Classroom (building, room-number, capacity)
Department (dept-name, building, budget)
Section (course-id, section-id, semester, year, building, room-number, time-slot-id)
Teaches (id, course-id, section-id, semester, year)
Advisor(s-id, i-id)
Time-slot (time-slot-id, day, start-time, end-time)
Prereq (course-id, prereq-id)

Comment: If you were given script for those tables, then the script was **wrong** because there's no way you'll make it work the way you tried to. I suggested what I thought would be useful and there's nothing I'd like to add to it.